# Create An AD User Profile

Tags: active-directory, profile

I am new to server management. I have a set of AD users. I can log on as each user, (their name is in the start menu), but they always each get the same profile (shared My Documents (H:/) etc).

What steps are required to give each user their own My Documents / Favourites etc, that they can access on any networked computer?  There are about 50-100 users.

In Active Directory Users and Groups, the profile tab of each user is empty.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you may have folder redirection in place via group policy.

I would check your group policies and run an RSOP (Resultant Set of Policy) against a machine and/or user account to see which policies are getting applied.

RSOP:

http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/Generating-Resultant-Set-Policy-Queries.html

Here is more information on folder redirection:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782799%28WS.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What you describe it's not standard Active Directory behaviour, so you probably have some policy or other settings in place which is creating that; standard behaviour is for each user to have its own profile and to have it stored locally on the computer where s/he logs on, so:

- Each user who logs on to a computer for the first time gets a new profile.
- Each user who logs on again to a computer where s/he logged on before gets the last profile that has been saved on that machine.
- Each user who logged on to a computer but logs on to another one for the first time gets a new profile there, too.

First of all, you should solve this problem, or nothing else is going to work as it should.

---

What you seem to want is for your users to:

- Have each one his/her own profile.
- Have only one profile regardless of the actual machine where they log on.

This *can* be accomplished with the so-called "roaming profiles", which has been around since Windows NT. There is plenty of documentation around about them , but basically you set them up by:

- Creating a network share where they will be centrally stored
- Populating the "Profile" field in the user properties with a path like `\\servername\share\username`. You can actually use a variable here instead of the actual username, so `\\servername\share\%username%` will work, too: you can simply set it for all your users at the same time, an each one of them will get his/her own profile in a distinct folder.

Be careful with roaming profiles, as their content is fully synchronized between the server and the client at each logon/logoff, and their size can grow very quicly if your users are used to store big things in their Documents folder or on their desktops; folder redirection can help you mitigate this.